# JqPlot 2 Y axis :Only display horizontal grid line of the left axe

Tags: jquery, graphics, jqplot

Someone know how I could hide the horizontal grid line of the secondary y axis (right)?

Sometimes, a picture of a problem is more easy to understand than a long description :

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be of much benefit to see your code.
Anyway what I think is you should set `showGridline` option for `tickOptions` for appropriate axes, and you are done.

```
   axes: {    
      grid: {
         drawBorder: false
      },
      yaxis: {
         tickOptions: {
            showGridline: false
         }
      }     
  }
```

[The above solution was first suggested here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jqplot-users/XYnpxb5t3q8)

In your case it will be `y2axis` that you are after.

Comment: Thanks @Bouillou for the comment but I cannot take the credit for the solution. It all belongs to `Chris Leonello`, the original source is linked in the answer. BTW Chris is the creator, developer and maintainer of the great `jqPlot` :) Good day to you.

Comment: Using drawBorder:false in grid i am only able to remove x axis line.Its not removing on Y axis :( . My requirement is to show dotted lines for x axis and Y axis.Can anyone please help.I am using jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,jqplot.BarRenderer and jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer

Comment: @Surya please start a new, your own, question where you can present your problem better. This way you will get more attention.